# How to use react with material ui along with python-django

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, material-ui

I need help to use react with material ui components in web application.

The following key technologies i **worked on for several projects**:

[Materialize CSS](https://materializecss.com/), **Javascript**, **Jquery**.

The following key technologies that i **want to work with for new projects**:

[Material UI](https://material-ui.com/), [React](https://reactjs.org/)

Is it good idea to work with react or to have Angular ?

How to start making a project having both django and react with material UI components?

References :

- https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/getting-started-with-material-ui-for-react-material-design-for-react-364b2688b555
- https://medium.com/@TechMagic/reactjs-vs-angular5-vs-vue-js-what-to-choose-in-2018-b91e028fa91d

Answer (score 0):

Front-end and backend are two separated things.

- You can use whatever database, because your backend will work with that.
- You can use whatever as backend.
- React/vue/angular don't care how you will be communicating with server or what backend you use.

You can start with set up frontend development for react using for instance [facebook-create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) which would set up basic development boilerplate. You will also need to take care of client-side routing (you can use [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) and you will need some way to comunicate with your backend for example with ajax calls to get your data using ES6 `fetch()` or some js library like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

It is up to you how you will handle backend but i would recommend you to use [RESTfull API with django](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) which would be communicating with your front-end

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this on a project right now. The project was set up for me with Docker however, which I'd recommend, it's very well contained. But if you don't want to use Docker you could use [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/). I'd make sure this is in a separate directory from your Django project, but in the same git repo.

`create-react-app` will create a development server for you to develop the front end with.

You'll need a few other libraries in your React code besides [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) to fill a couple other needs:

- client-side routing, I recommend [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) (for use with MUI see [this docs page](https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/#third-party-routing-library))
- communication with the backend Django server, I recommend [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/).

Traditionally you'd use a RESTful API but these are very difficult to design well and have limitations in traversability and ability to change over time. I think that GraphQL is the future of web APIs and everyone should check it out.

To implement a GraphQL API in Django you can use [graphene-django](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django) which integrates well with Django's ORM (models). It's documentation is thin, but I've found it works very well.

On the client side there's a few React libraries for connecting to servers with a GraphQL API. I'm using [Relay](http://facebook.github.io/relay/en/) which is from the same developers as React and GraphQL, but [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) could also be a good option depending on the state of its development.

Eventually, when you deploy the project you'll need to compile production static files out of `create-react-app` or Webpack or whatever you're using to compile your React code. Then put the static files in a place that can serve them on your site. If you're using a production web sever like nginx the static files can be served directly without reaching Django.

Answer (score 0):

The following key technologies i worked on for several projects:

Backend : Python-Django (MySQL)

Frontend : Materialize CSS, Javascript, Jquery.
The following key technologies that i want to work with for new projects:

> **What does work mean? If you can write api's in the backend.Go ahead and write some api's using django framework.**

Backend : Python-Django (MySQL)
Frontend : Material UI, React
So can you guys help me out to implement this.

> **What do u mean by implement? Go ahead and find a nice react + material ui + webpack boilerplate and start the application. Try to Consume
>   your backend api's through it.**

Is it good idea to work with react or to have Angular ?

> **Long discussion,You would have got this answer if you read the article that you posted**

Do i need to switch to other database ?

> **It depends on your project**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader which is a good strategy for launch react build with django (i use django rest) and you can use an html in jinja template where you inject the react JS code

You can eject or use config override top override the default native webpack configuration present in react JS https://www.npmjs.com/package/config-override

Answer (score 0):

I think you should see Preact, which is react integrated in any MVC templating, with that you can override some places of templates by their ids.

By this solution you can inject material ui code inside your templates form or others has you need.

For the injection you need to use custom element,
https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/web-components/#creating-a-web-component